# wpf usercontrol states, modifying height

Tags: wpf, animation, user-controls, height, states

I am a little bit confused of states and animations in WPF.

I would like to make a usercontrol. This usercontrol will contains (inside the main grid) 2 another grid. One of them would be HEADER and second one will be CONTENT. If user click on header, content will expand, otherwise will be collapsed. And i would like to animation that expanding (Slide down the content from the header).

Basicaly i would like to do that by states (for future purpose). Problem is, if i add the states and i am using the slide efect with transformation, the content of this grid (CONTENT GRID) is transformed as well. So i would like to use the states with modifying just the height of the element. If u modify only the element, no animation appear and it just change its height at once.

The hierarchy looks like: 
--- wrapper grid 
------ header grid 
--------- content of header 
------ content grid 
--------- content of content grid (like buttons, labels, etc)

The visualstates looks like:

```
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:1"/>
            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
            <VisualState x:Name="Expanded"/>
            <VisualState x:Name="Collapsed">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <x:Double>0</x:Double>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Any advice to see the expanding and collapsing the grid with modifying height by states?
With animation only it works perfect, but its better for me to do it with states, how i said, for future purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i found a answer. For now it works but i am trying to understanding that changes.

code of visualstates in here:

```
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
            <VisualState x:Name="Expanded">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation EnableDependentAnimation="True" Storyboard.TargetName="grid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" From="0" To="366" Duration="0:0:0.600" />
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Collapsed">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation EnableDependentAnimation="True" Storyboard.TargetName="grid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" From="366" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.600" />
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

The important line is:

```
<DoubleAnimation EnableDependentAnimation="True" Storyboard.TargetName="grid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" From="366" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.600" />
```

I found its needed to have EnableDependantAnimation true.

Now it works as a charm, but i do not like that FROM TO set. But its possibly the best i can do in here.